# React typescript, how to find all words between '#' in the string

Tags: reactjs, typescript, replace, find

I've got a question about some solution for my problem.. I need to find all words between '#' in the string...

example:

```
    const str = `<Table striped bordered hover>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#project name#</th>
      <th>#First Name#</th>
      <th>#Last Name#</th>
      <th>#Username#</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td colSpan="2">#Footer#</td>
      <td>#social media#</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</Table>
<p> normal text: #Published data# </p>
`
```

is there any method? I have to find in my table that I could to replace those words for words from database. I thought about proptype.replaceAll, but I couldn't solve it by this :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String.prototype.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) should work.  Perhaps you weren't using it correctly?  We want to use a `RegExp` that lazily matches the text between two `#` symbols with a capture group.  Then you can use whatever callback function to replace the values.

The Typescript is a little weird because TS doesn't know that our `RegExp` has a capture group and that we will always get a `string` as the second argument of the `replacer` function.  It is typed such that the second argument, which is our capture group, could be `any` type.

```
/**
 * this is where you implement your actual replacement logic
 */
const findReplacement = (text: string) => {
    switch (text.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'project name':
            return '<span class="project">Project</span>';
        case 'footer':
            return "Replacement for Footer";
        default:
            return text;
    }
}

/**
 * function to handle a string like your example
 */
const processTemplate = (text: string) => {
    return text.replaceAll(
        /#(.*?)#/g, 
        (_, match) => findReplacement(match)
    );
}
```

Try it on your string with

```
console.log(processTemplate(str));
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#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-gu21W4gvMbpis2PUmMa1kh+61B8PXsh8HGAHINXBT4Az0Hz43xdJsNeT6dDncz40AVQyXXXm+33enfZbW7wHdnrcrOmIs8CvZ-+VbTsAEZp07M9OwAWS4fA6VA-9f3gTsAHl4DiODwK8AABKgdFIdCHy3J8HwpeCe0QrwACZ8IHciACleFIAtqLncjhTrLo4mYZiCkArCAXgbie0I-8-wwgBmQSEPLFQ6AAZUGZhJgo+ZjXeU4CDvMDuyk4dUFIHhkEEN0y0MzSROE594E-b8oDWfMi1wLtehoHxmBed0hDVJxjQWcgizQPByx0D0uGNISXOzb5lFUPSGGiKRpEsAVcCFUVaFGGxLBcbJtiAA)

Runnable Stack Snippet (no TS)

```js
const findReplacement = (text) => {
    switch (text.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'project name':
            return '<span class="project">Project</span>';
        case 'footer':
            return "Replacement for Footer";
        default:
            return text;
    }
}

const processTemplate = (text) => {
    return text.replaceAll(
        /#(.*?)#/g, 
        (_, match) => findReplacement(match)
    );
}

const str = `<Table striped bordered hover>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#project name#</th>
      <th>#First Name#</th>
      <th>#Last Name#</th>
      <th>#Username#</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td colSpan="2">#Footer#</td>
      <td>#social media#</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</Table>
<p> normal text: #Published data# </p>`;

console.log(processTemplate(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const str = `<Table striped bordered hover>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#project name#</th>
      <th>#First Name#</th>
      <th>#Last Name#</th>
      <th>#Username#</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td colSpan="2">#Footer#</td>
      <td>#social media#</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</Table>
<p> normal text: #Published data# </p>`;
    const words = [];
    let start = false;
    let word = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if (str[i] === "#") {
        if (start) words.push(word);
        word = "";
        start = !start;
      } else {
        if (start) {
          word += str[i];
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(words);
```